# FileUtils crashes android with exception. been searching and trying to fix for days! logcat included

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Just a simple copy dir command but i cant get it to work without crashing on me : ( i know your not meant to hardcode file locations but i just want to get it working at this stage

```
public void gogogo(String[] args) {

    String source = "/data/data/com.example.fuckinggrrr/files/DATS"; 
    //"/mnt/sdcard/DATS/";
    File srcDir2 = new File(source);

    String destination = "/mnt/sdcard/DATS/";
    File destDir2 = new File(destination);

    try {
        FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(srcDir2, destDir2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here is the logcat error:

```
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method gogogo(View) in the activity class com.example.fuckinggrrr.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: gogogo [class android.view.View]
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3606)
04-23 09:31:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(14943):    ... 11 more
04-23 09:31:15.284: D/Process(14943): killProcess, pid=14943
```

so confused. helped appreciated!

Comment: is `gogogo()` method is `OnClickListener` for any `View`?

Comment: fixed it!! gogogo(String[] args) needed to be gogogo(View v)

Comment: While I'm glad you fixed it yourself (that kind of progress is important for your coding career), you should re-read your question, especially the title. As you can see, the error has nothing to do with the FileUtils...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use XML to define onClick actions. It's error prone and very VERY slow. Set an `OnclickListener` via java code.

As Thrakbad pointed out, if you want to go the XML way (which is a bad idea), you need to fix the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your method `gogogo` is set as an click listener for a button (perhaps from your layout?). thats why it looks for a method with the signature `gogogo(View)`. What you have is a method with the signature `gogogo(String[])`.